# Some Element in my Python Set() ended becoming hexadecimal

Tags: python, csv, parsing, set

I was trying to parse a fortinet log into csv file. Part of the code will read all 4 million lines in the log file and save any word before an "=" sign as an element in a set(). These element will become the csv headers.

When trying to parse 500000 lines, the set looks ok, but when I try to parse 1 million lines, some elements starts to become long hexadecimal values.

Attached is how it looked like in the end.

```
C:\Python27>python.exe D:\parser\logtocsv.py
* Finding Column Headers 2018-07-24 08:59:23
completed 1517027 lines
set(['', 'shapersentname', 'tuple-num', 'bandwidth', 'totalsession', 'disk', 'hook', 'HTTP/1.1in.css?ver', 'group', 'HTTP/1.13&amp;ip', 'to',
'\xe7\xbf\xbb\xe4\xba\x86\xe5\x8d\x8a\xe5\xa4\xa9\xe6\x89\x8d\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\xe4\xbd\xa0\xef\xbc\x8cJia\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe7\x
94\xa8\xe6\x89\xa3\xe5\x8f\xb7706772123\xe5\x88\xab\xe5\x86\x8d\xe5\x88\xa0\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x95\xa6~', 'HTTP/1.1?cms_redirect', 'analyticscksu
m', 'devname', 'setuprate', 'appact', 'fazlograte', 'recipient', 'sentpkt', 'shaperrcvdname', 'level', 'subtype', 'attackid', 'appid', 'dir',
'profile', 'sentbyte', 'crscore', 'duration', 'analyticssubmit', 'subject', 'error', 'eventtype', 'dstcountry', 'countweb', 'filename', 'diskl
ograte', 'applist', 'fcni', 'ref', 'method', 'mem', 'incidentserialno', 'processtime', 'reason', 'dstintf', 'srcintf', 'countav', 'sender', 'v
irusid', 'logid', 'HTTP/1.1ver', 'act', 'action', 'carrier_ep', 'policyid', 'dstip', 'rcvdbyte', 'srccountry', 'dtype', 'app', 'utmaction', 's
rcip', '\xe7\xbf\xbb\xe4\xba\x86\xe5\x8d\x8a\xe5\xa4\xa9\xe6\x89\x8d\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\xe4\xbd\xa0\xef\xbc\x8cJia\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\xb8\xb
8\xe7\x94\xa8\xe6\x89\xa3\xe5\x8f\xb7715859168\xe5\x88\xab\xe5\x86\x8d\xe5\x88\xa0\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x95\xa6~', 'crlevel', 'shaperdropsentbyte',
 'rsso_key', 'from', 'log', 'service', 'fdni', 'devid', '\xe5\xbe\x88\xe5\xbc\x80\xe5\xbf\x83\xef\xbc\x8c\xe8\x83\xbd\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\
xe4\xbd\xa0\xef\xbc\x81Jia\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe7\x94\xa8q\xe5\x8f\xb7717598789\xe5\x88\xab\xe5\xbf\x98\xe4\xba\x86\xef\xbc\x
81', 'attack', 'filesize', 'logdesc', 'poluuid', 'msg', 'type', 'direction', 'authproto', 'sessionid', 'shaperdroprcvdbyte', 'countips', 'coun
t', 'datarange', 'cat', 'ui', 'countapp', 'rcvdpkt', 'quarskip', 'vd', 'craction', 'file', 'apprisk', 'severity', 'proto', 'hostname', 'new_st
atus', 'attachment', 'dstport', 'status', 'acct_stat', 'time', 'fsci', 'catdesc', 'virus', 'reporttype', 'user', 'reqtype', 'date', 'old_statu
s', 'countemail', 'url', 'appcat', 'srcport', 'command', 'trandisp', 'cpu'])
pause^A
```

Below is the part of my code that saves the elements in my set():

```
import csv
import time
import datetime
def findColumnHeaders(log_file_path):
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print "* Finding Column Headers " + st 
    f = open(log_file_path, "r")
    col_headers = set() # create empty set for all column headers
    col_headers_old = set()
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]# List of lines to iterate through
    current_col_header = ""
    start = False
    count = 0
    letter_chr = 0
    line_number = 0
    letter_number = 0
    for line in content:
        letter_number = 0
        line_number += 1
        for letter in line:
            letter_number += 1
            if letter == " ":
                # space means start taking in new col_value
                # data is in this structure with space prior to column names -> " column=col_value"
                start = True
                current_col_header = ""
            elif letter == "=":
                # when hits "=", means that prior word is a column col_value -> "column=col_value"   
                col_headers.add(current_col_header)                  
                # reset current_col_header to empty string
                current_col_header = ""
                # only take in once another space has been encountered
                start = False               
                continue
            elif start:
                current_col_header += letter
            # else, do nothing
    print "completed " + str(line_number) + " lines"
    print col_headers
    raw_input("pause")
    return col_headers
```

Comment: Please post the actual text in your question, not a scaled-down screenshot of your txt.

Comment: Anyway, without being able to read anything, my guess (at about 2:1 odds) is that what you actually have is either Python 2 strings or Python 3 bytes values representing Unicode strings, most of which are pure-ASCII, but a few of which are not, and so when you print out the UTF-8-encoded or Latin-1-encoded or cp1252-encoded or whatever bytes, those non-ASCII characters show up as `\xc3\xa9` or `\xe9` instead of `é`, and all you need to do is `decode` with the right encoding to get Python 2 unicode or Python 3 string values.

Comment: I changed my screenshot to text. I have also posted my code up. May I know how I should add the decode here?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're printing out UTF-8-encoded strings. For example, this:

```
'\xe7\xbf\xbb\xe4\xba\x86\xe5\x8d\x8a\xe5\xa4\xa9\xe6\x89\x8d\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x88\xb0\xe4\xbd\xa0\xef\xbc\x8cJia\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe7\x94\xa8\xe6\x89\xa3\xe5\x8f\xb7706772123\xe5\x88\xab\xe5\x86\x8d\xe5\x88\xa0\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x95\xa6~'
```

… is the UTF-8 encoding of this string:

```
翻了半天才找到你，Jia我常用扣号706772123别再删我啦~
```

What you want to do is `decode` your UTF-8 `str` byte strings to `unicode` text strings.

---

The cleanest place to do this is as early as possible—tell the file object itself to decode thing for you. You can use either [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) if you want to be compatible with Python 2.6 and earlier, or [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) if you want to be compatible with Python 3. Either way, you're also going to want to replace your string literals like `"="` with unicode literals like `u"="`. So, for example:

```
f = io.open(log_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
# ...
current_col_header = u""
# ...
        if letter == u" ":
        # etc.
```

---

The smallest change, on the other hand, is to do this as *late* as possible, manually decoding things only when you store them in the set:

```
col_headers.add(current_col_header.decode('utf-8')
```

… or even later, when you print things out:

```
print {header.decode('utf-8') for header in col_headers}
```

---

The benefit of the first approach is that if you wanted to look for any non-ASCII characters, you can do that with unicode string. For example, the first letter in the Chinese string as unicode is `u'翻'`, so you can just do `if letter == u'翻':`; the first byte in the Chinese string as UTF-8 is `'\xe7'`, so you can't do `if letter == '翻':` (and, while you *can* do `if letter == '\xe7'`, that would be incorrect, because lots of other character start with the same `\xe7` byte).

But if that's never going to be an issue, you can do it either way.

---

As a side note, because you're on Windows and using Python 2.7, trying to print non-ASCII strings may just not work. There are workarounds, but they're all painful. The easy solution is to switch to Python 3. (In fact, in Python 3, your whole problem would never have arisen in the first place, because files automatically decode UTF-8, and every string is automatically a Unicode string.) But if you can't upgrade for some reason, and you run into this problem, you will need one of those horrible workarounds.